# Can't Update Apt to get Recent Version of npm

Tags: apt, package-management, npm

I'm trying to install a more recent version of npm. On the [Ubuntu packages site for 19.10 Eon](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/npm) it lists the version as 5.8.0, which is perfect, but when I go to the command line and type
"apt show npm" it lists the version as 3.5.2

I've tried "sudo apt update" and there's no error, but afterwards apt still lists the version as 3.5.2

How do I update the repository so that apt lists the version as 5.8.0?

Thanks

Comment: What release are you running?  3.5.2 is correct for 18.04/bionic, are you using *bionic* (18.04) and not *eoan* (19.10) ?  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=npm&searchon=names

Comment: I don't know which I'm using, but since you say that, it's probably bionic. Is there a way to switch it to eoan?

Comment: `lsb_release -a` is one way to see what you're running.  If it's Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, it has two tested & supported upgrade paths, first was to the next release or 18.10 (now EOL & gone), second will be to 20.04 (*after 20.04.1's release*) where testing hasn't officially started as 20.04 is still in development..  Moving from 18.04 to 19.10 is possible (using method of *bump* to 18.10) but it was untested & is unsupported.  It'll mean moving yourself off the LTS path and onto a standard release halfway thru it's supported life already (18.04 is not yet half-way).   Be sure you want to do it.

Comment: I checked and it is bionic. I probably won't take the risk of moving to 19.10, but thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can install a more recent version from here:

https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md

**Example for version :Node.js v13.x:**

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_13.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```